# does google pixel speech to text use google cloud Speech-to-Text API

Tags: android, api, pixel

are google pixel speech to text using the same google cloud speech to text API?

my understanding is google pixel speech to text is offline.
and many speech to text are offline now.

where can i find an offline speech to text API for my android development work

https://medium.com/voice-tech-podcast/android-speech-to-text-tutorial-8f6fa71606ac

only manage to find this website but its speech need to go google cloud.